# How to connect Scalix as Exchange client – internal and external URL?

Tags: macos, email, exchange

We're using **Scalix v12.7** for emails and calendars and it works – mostly... but there is one thing I couldn't figure out yet:

**What settings are needed to connect the macOS email / calendar client using Exchange?**

I'm using an Exchange account setting on iOS which automatically figured out all needed settings. This setup supports PUSH which is the main reason why I prefer it over IMAP. But I've had no luck using an Exchange account with macOS so far. It fails to connect and asks for an **internal and external URL** – which I couldn't figure out yet. I hope to solve some calendar issues using Exchange on macOS.

[image: 1st step]

[image: 2nd step]

Any Ideas?

Comment: What's the detailed error message when "It fails to connect and asks for an internal and external URL "?

Comment: macOS simply refuses to add the account without that information. Automatic detection fails and the user is asked for that info.

Comment: I've added some images to make it clearer.